# Are the phases of entangled photons correlated?

Tags: photons, quantum-entanglement

I know the polarization of entangled photons are correlated, but are the phases of the wavelengths correlated as well?

Comment: Depends which degrees of freedom are entangled.  You need to be more precise.

Answer (score -2):

Good question, yes because if they’re not in phase they’re not entangled. That’s one reason there can be loopholes and why experiments are not perfect. Two entangled photons could be out of phase if traveling different distances to their targets. This would give false or skewed results because large percent of detections may not qualify.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopholes_in_Bell_test_experiments